# How to insert ≥ and °C symbols into the text in the boxes of flowcharts using DiagrammeR?

Tags: r, symbols, flowchart

I am user DiagrammeR to make flowcharts. I need to insert ≥ and °C special characters (symbols) into the text in the boxes of the flowchart.  How can I get the ≥ and ° symbols to appear in the text?

e.g.,

```
grViz("

digraph boxes_and_circles {

#add node statements
node[shape = rectangle,
      style = open,
      color = skyblue2,
      fontname = Helvetica]
#Node definitions with substituted label text
R1 [label = 'Oral temp ≥38.3°C × 1 \nor oral temp 38.0 to 38.2°C × 1h \n or axillary temp ≥37.8°C × 1 \nSTOP LEVOFLOXACIN']
#... etc.
```

Comment: You can use html ... `R1 [label = 'Oral temp &ge;38.3&deg;C × 1 \nor oral temp 38.0 to 38.2&deg;C × 1h \n or axillary temp &ge; 37.8&deg;C × 1 \nSTOP LEVOFLOXACIN']` . So `&deg;` and `&ge;` used for degrees and greater and equal than

Answer (score 1):

The greater than and degree symbols are rendering in the text just fine for me.

Try running this example to double check that this isn't due to another problem somewhere in your diagram code that hasn't been included in your question.

```
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("
  digraph boxes_and_circles {

    # Node statements
    node[shape = rectangle]
    node1 [label = 'Test ≥']
    node2 [label = 'Test °C']

    node1 -> node2
  }
")
```